# Can you StringFormat the NavigateUri property for Hyperlinks during XAML property databinding?

Tags: wpf, xaml, string, hyperlink, string-formatting

Is there an easy way to transform or format a string as part of WPF data binding?

Suppose I want to create a WPF Hyperlink element based on a string tag.

```
<Hyperlink NavigateUri="{Binding Tag}">
    <Run Text="{Binding Tag}" />
</Hyperlink>
```

But I need to transform the Tag first for the NavigateUri property to make it a true hyperlink or PackUri.

For instance, if my tag were "folksonomy" I'd want to create a string like: `http://www.example.com/tags/tagview?tag=folksonomy`

What's the best way to achieve this? Is there a string manipulation function in XAML? Do I have to write a converter? Do I have to build a whole separate ViewModel class just to do a little string formatting?

**UPDATE:** There appears to be something strange going on with the Hyperlink element. I can get the StringFormat syntax suggested in the answers to work for the Text property of an ordinary TextBlock, but not for the NavigateUri property of a Hyperlink.

As one answer noted, this is likely due to the fact that the NavigateUri property officially takes a Uri, not a string. Apparently a custom converter or ViewModel property will be required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the string formatting capabilities of bindings:

```
<Hyperlink NavigateUri="{Binding Tag, StringFormat=http://www.example.com/tags/tagview?tag={0}}">
    <Run Text="{Binding Tag}" />
</Hyperlink>
```

Comment: Hmmm. I can get this to work for the TextBlock element's Text property, but not for Hyperlink's NavigateUri or Tooltip properties.

Comment: Interesting. Probably because the target type is `Uri` rather than `String`. You might need to resort to your own converter, or a separate property on your view model.

Comment: That makes sense for the NavigateUri method, but it's interesting that the Tooltip won't take the StringFormat either. It seems like StringFormat just wasn't implemented at all. Maybe because Hyperlink lives in the System.Windows.Documents namespace?

Comment: Anyway, it looks like I'll have to use a custom converter or ViewModel property to format the strings properly. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Like Kent said you can use string formatting assuming you are on .NET 3.5 SP1 (string formatting was added as part of SP1). Good Samples here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/llobo/archive/2008/05/19/wpf-3-5-sp1-feature-stringformat.aspx

If you aren't on .NET 3.5 SP1 or the string format approach becomes too messy you would want to us an IValueConverter http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx

Comment: The StringFormat syntax only works with properties whose underlying type is string, so that won't work for NavigateUri, which has a Uri as its underlying property. I'll have to use an IValueConverter.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else stumbling across this thread seeking a solution, I found Foovanadil's suggested IValueConverter worked well for me.

```
<TextBlock> 
    <Hyperlink Name="lnkGoogle" NavigateUri="{Binding Path=Alert.Query,Converter={View:UriConverter},ConverterParameter=google}" RequestNavigate="Hyperlink_RequestNavigate">
        Find news on Google
    </Hyperlink>
</TextBlock>
```

With the converter class in my codebehind:

```
public class UriConverter : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            string address = string.Empty;
            switch ((string)parameter)
            {
                case "google":
                    address = "http://www.google.co.uk/news?q=" + value;
                    break;                    
            }

            Uri path = new Uri(@address);
            return path;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override object ProvideValue(System.IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            return this;
        }
    }
```